# Adding temporary message on static site

Tags: hugo

I have a Hugo based static site and have a requirement for a non-technical user to be able to add some "office temporarily closed" message.

My thought is to create some tiny UI that allows the non-technical user to login and modify an S3 bucket with the message.

The static site will have a static link to that s3 bucket and display what ever is in it.

Is there a more HUGO way to do that?  Or do I just end up rolling my own.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ‘Hugo way’ for a non-technical user to do anything, given that Hugo is designed for those who have a fairly decent grasp of html at a minimum and web development in general.